# what is the difference in these queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was trying to improve on a previously written query . here's that query-

```
select tq.feature as Feature, tq.Total, pq.Passed 
from (
  select feature, count(distinct id) as Total 
  from X.results 
  where ver = '4.2' 
  group by feature
) as tq 
LEFT JOIN (
  select feature, count(distinct id) as Passed 
  from X.results 
  where ver = '4.2' and result = 'pass' 
  group by feature
) as pq USING (feature);
```

This is the query i wrote.But the result seems to be different .Am is missing something here ?

```
select feature,count(distinct id) as totalcases,
  sum(case when result = 'PASS' then  1 else 0 end) as passed 
from X.results 
where ver='4.2' 
group by feature 
order by feature;
```

I'm a real noob in sql so forgive me if it's something silly ..

Comment: post your result  for both queries and what is your expected result.

Comment: your 1st query counts distinct id's for pass. Your second query doesn't. it just gets the count of records with PASS for each feature

Comment: the sum after count(distinct id) , won't that consider only distinct ids  ?

Comment: no, your passed column is only computed based on the check `result = 'PASS'` for all rows which satisfy this condition for a feature, it will only count those rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to group based on both a results and feature and then do another aggregate again on just feature. Something like this.

```
SELECT 
    feature,
    SUM(id_count) totalcases,
    SUM(CASE WHEN result = 'PASS' THEN id_count ELSE 0 END) passed
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    feature,
    CASE WHEN result = 'PASS' THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'OTHER' END result,
    COUNT(distinct id) id_count
    FROM x.results
    WHERE ver='4.2' 
    GROUP BY feature,CASE WHEN result = 'PASS' THEN 'PASS' ELSE 'OTHER' END
) x
GROUP BY feature
ORDER BY feature
```

Comment: This seems to be working . Thanks. I'll see what mistake i did.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT feature, count(distinct id) AS Total,
  count(distinct if (result='pass', id, null)) AS passed
FROM X.results
WHERE ver = '4.2'
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

This SQL is different from yours, please see the result as below:

[image]

Comment: well, this gives the same result as my query . :|

Comment: My SQL is different from yours. If result happened to be same, could you give us a list of sample data?